# Is the given if statement correct in PHP?

Tags: php

Recently came across code in Symfony. Can please somebody help me understand this `if` statement? I never saw an expression like such before.

```
if (1 > $split_length = (int) $split_length) {
    trigger_error('The length of each segment must be greater than zero', E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why are you wanting to understand? Or better put, what's tripping you up about the code statement?

Comment: Hello @treyBake, is that expression even correct? Using an assignment after an expression.

Comment: It is indeed, or else the whole system would fatal error :) (or wherever the code was being used) - Although it's not my preferred code style, it is valid code. As explained in the answer given :) but personally, I still prefer assignment before use

Comment: Assigning variables inside an expression are, in many coding standards, frowned upon, since it can be unclear if it's meant to be an assignment or if it's a typo when comparing. However, syntax wise, it's completely valid.

Comment: The statement is the part contained within the curly braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning a value to a variable also returns the assigned value. If you run

```
echo $a = 5;
```

it will print out 5 and the value 5 is assigned to the variable $a.

So the part

```
$split_length = (int) $split_length
```

casts $split_length to int and also returns the assigned value.

This returned value is then used in the comparison if it is smaller than 1. If you add some (not necessary) brackets it may get clearer:

```
if (   1 > ($split_length = (int) $split_length)   )
```

Comment: Does PHP evaluates the expression from right to left in an IF statement? @simirimia

Comment: Maybe it will influence other code below (not included in question) but wouldn't `if (1 >  (int) $split_length)` be shorter and in this case sufficient?

Comment: the order depends on the operator. Check this for details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @jrswgtr: it is not the same. Your code would cast $split_length for the comparission, but the value of $split_length would still be the orignal value. Or yes, for the code we see there is no difference. But it may change the behavior of the following code.

Comment: @jrswgtr - Then wouldn't `if (1 > $split_length)` be even shorter since PHP will do the type juggling for you? :-)

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash PHP does not evaluate the expression in different ways in `if` conditions and in other contexts. `a > b > c` is evaluated as `(a > b) > c` because the comparison operators associate from left to right and `a = b = c` is evaluated as `a = (b = c)` because the assignment operators associate from right to left. On the other hand, `a > b = c` evaluates to `a > (b = c)` because `(a > b) = c` doesn't make any sense; `a > b` produces a r-value (`true` or `false`) and a r-value cannot be modified (the assignment operator modifies its left operand).